# Unable to cast type Metadata to type Layout

Tags: metadata-api, page-layout, c#

Does anybody have an idea why i get the mentioned exception on the following line of code:

```
Layout layout =
   (Layout)service.readMetadata("Layout", new string[] {"Object__c-Object Layout"})[0];
```

I'm following the Andrew Fawcett blog [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/12/24/updating-layouts-in-apex/) for read/update layout.

```
        public MetadataCreator(SalesforceContext context)
        {
            _metadataService = new MetadataService();
            _metadataService.Url = context.InstanceUrl + "/services/Soap/m/32.0/" + context.User.OrganizationId;
            _metadataService.SessionHeaderValue = new MetadataApiReference.SessionHeader();
            _metadataService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = context.AccessToken;           
        }
        private MetadataService _metadataService;

        public void GetLayout()
        {
            Layout result = (Layout)_metadataService.readMetadata("Layout", new string[] { "Macro-Macro Layout" })[0];
            //More code to follow
        }
```

**EDIT: The `ReadResult` class was not generated.**

```
<xsd:complexType name="ReadResult">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="records" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:Metadata"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dummyFriend" type="tns:Metadata"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

After adding dummy element in the xml file, tha class was generated, but again I'm not able to cast Metadata to any other Metadata Type. From the Metadata API:

> 2. Invoke the readMetadata() call. For the first argument, pass in the name of the metadata type. The metadata type must match one of the values returned by the describeMetadata() call. For the second argument, pass in an array of full names corresponding to the components you wish to get. The full names must match one or more full names returned by the listMetadata() call.

I have implementented the bellow Method

```
    public void GetLayout()
    {
        try
        {
            var describeMetadata = _metadataService.describeMetadata(32.0);
            var type = describeMetadata.metadataObjects.First(x => x.xmlName.Equals("Layout")).xmlName;

            var query = new ListMetadataQuery();
            query.type = type;
            var queries = new ListMetadataQuery[] { query };
            var fileProps = _metadataService.listMetadata(queries, 32.0);
            var layoutFullName = fileProps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.type.Equals(type)).fullName;

            var result = _metadataService.readMetadata(type, new string[] { layoutFullName });
            // ....
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                //....
            }
        }
```

The returned `result` contains a record with `fullName=null` and that behavior is for any Metadata Type.

**The Solution**
Thanks to @Peter de Jong, i was able to fix this issue. I have translated the Java method to C# and adjust it to my needs the problem is gone.

```
public void readCustomObjectSync() { 
 try { 
     ReadResult readResult =
     metadataConnection.readMetadata("CustomObject", new String[] {"MyCustomObject1__c", "MyCustomObject2__c" }); 
     Metadata[] mdInfo = readResult.getRecords(); 
     System.out.println("Number of component info returned: " + mdInfo.length); 
     for (Metadata md : mdInfo) { 
        if (md != null) { 
            CustomObject obj = (CustomObject) md; 
            System.out.println("Custom object full name: " + obj.getFullName()); 
            System.out.println("Label: " + obj.getLabel()); 
            System.out.println("Number of custom fields: " + obj.getFields().length); 
            System.out.println("Sharing model: " + obj.getSharingModel()); 
        } else { 
            System.out.println("Empty metadata."); 
        } 
    } 
} catch (ConnectionException ce) { 
        ce.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

}

**The real cause of the problem:**

I couldn't cast Metadata to type Layout, because the Full Name needs to be qualified twice with the Namespace. For example:

```
 MetadataService.Layout layout =
   (MetadataService.Layout) service.readMetadata('Layout',
      new String[] { 'PackagePrefix__Object__c-PackagePrefix__LayoutName' }).getRecords()[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readMetaData method results indeed in an instance of the implemented IReadResult Class.
Can you cast the result of readMetaData to ReadLayoutResult and invoke .getRecords()? .getRecords should return a list of instantiated Metadata.

Comment: I don't have such type `ReadLayoutResult `.

Comment: MetadataService.ReadLayoutResult

Comment: No, just `ReadResult`. I have searched for it in the Metadata.xml, downloaded from salesforce, but it's not avialable there either.

Comment: At http://bit.ly/1yK5PGo , I read `public class ReadLayoutResult implements IReadResult { <SNIP> }`

Comment: Well, do i have to implement it manually in my generated MetadataService class? Is this going to help?

Comment: The readme at https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi suggests to install the code of the creator of apex-mdapi. Quote: `One option is to download the Metadata WSDL from the Tools page under the Develop menu and attempt to generate Apex code from this, using the Generate from WSDL button. This does not work straight away, some changes to the WSDL and updates to the generated code is required. Fortunately this library has done all this for you, so all you need to do is take the MetadataService.cls and MetadataServiceTest.cls and get started with the examples included.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23019/discussion-between-vortex-and-peter-de-jong).

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the **.getRecords()** call?

```
Layout layout = (Layout)service.readMetadata("Layout", new string[] {"Object__c-Object Layout"}).getRecords()[0];
```

Comment: I don't have .getRecords() method.

Comment: `readMetadata()` should return an `IReadResult`, this interface has the `getRecords()` method so I'm not sure why you can't access it. Could you post more of your code for us to review?

Comment: See my edited qustion.